# What are survival tools I should have when in the wilderness?

Tags: survival, wilderness, lost

When venturing out into the wilderness, what are crucial things I  should bring?

Comment: This type of question doesn't have a right answer, and could lead to a lot of bickering...

Comment: See, the bickering has already started under Mat's answer ;)

Comment: Common sense...

Comment: Please don't edit random ancients questions changing their meaning. If you have a question to ask, post it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of all the things that I listed bellow I think the most important is warm clothing and a water container. A knife you can make by splinting hard rock. Remember you need this (in order of importance):

1. Air to breath,
2. Shelter to keep warm,
3. Water to function,
4. Food to keep going.

Items:

- Clothing, enough layers for the season
- Sleeping bag or thick wool blanket
- Fixed blade 9" Knife
- Water container you can boil water in and carry around with you
- Optionally two 55 gallon industrial garbage bags for rain protection.
- First aid kit
- If you are not good forager and/or hunter than some food for the time you are going to be in the wilderness.

Cordage you can make from cambium or any other natural source suitable for that purpose.

You can make fire by building fire bow-drill. You got the knife and cordage you already made for it.

[image]

You can create filter from articles of clothing suspended on tripod. After you are done filtering the water you should boil it as well.

[image]

You can build debris shelter in your camp instead for lugging around tent.

You could do with a lot less but I found this to be OK comfort zone.

Comment: Oh come on, bring a lighter and matches.

Comment: Yes, those are good because they will work even when wet and last a long time. I really think your list should include them. If anything goes wrong, the last thing you want to struggle with is fire!

Comment: @MatBanik Two words - jacket pockets.